# Login string with accent from android application to PHP script

Tags: php, android, string

I'm developping an Android application.
This app has to connect to a server with login and password. This launches a PHP script on the remote server which then get the login and password strings.
When I use a character such "é" in the login (which is possible), the PHP script get the character "�".

How to get the correct character in my PHP script ?
Thanks.

Comment: Configure character set your Android app side to send this character, php can receive that as it is

Comment: Seems to be a character set issue (e.g UTF-8, LATIN1) .

Comment: android side : `connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");` or whatever is appropriate to your java http client, and whether you are trying to send json in a POST.

Comment: As I use HttpPost to connect :
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList, "UTF-8"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the character to `UTF-8` using `mb_convert_encoding()` in PHP

```
// PHP
$enc = mb_convert_encoding("é", "UTF-8");
echo $enc;
```

Set `charset=UTF-8` in your Android application HTTP client as well.

```
// JAVA
byte[] bytes = "é".getBytes("UTF-8"); 
String body = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```